# Android ListView requires two fingers to scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a rather simple layout that I am intending on using for basic chat in a fragment, but scrolling through the ListView requires me to place one finger on the screen on an item in the ListView and then scroll up or down with another finger. I was under the impression that a ListView should only require a single finger/touch to be able to scroll. Is there something I am overlooking in my layout, adapter or even potentially the code I am using to populate the adapter with?

Chat Layout XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/msgListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/form"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:scrollbarSize="3dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_width="252dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendMessageButton"
            android:layout_weight="0.72"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxHeight="80dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sendMessageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_send_button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ListView Adapter

```
public class ChatMessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    ArrayList<ChatMessage> chatMessageList;

    public ChatMessageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<ChatMessage> list) {
        chatMessageList = list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return chatMessageList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ChatMessage message = chatMessageList.get(position);
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_bubble, null);

        TextView msg = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        msg.setText(message.body);

        TextView dateTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.msgDateTime);
        dateTime.setText(message.dateTime);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.bubble_layout);
        LinearLayout parent_layout = (LinearLayout) vi
                .findViewById(R.id.bubble_layout_parent);

        // if message is mine then align to right
        if (message.isMine) {
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble2);
            parent_layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        // If not mine then align to left
        else {
            layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble1);
            parent_layout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
        msg.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        return vi;
    }

    public void add(ChatMessage object) {
        chatMessageList.add(object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem!
If you're using the navigation drawer, in the app_bar_main.xml change the CoordinatorLayout for the NestedScrollView

and then in your fragment in the scrollView set `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"`